How to model a marked temporal point process with unboundedly evolutionary integer event markers
I have a marked temporal point process (MTPP) where the number of discrete event types is unbounded. Each type of event occur several times and never happen again. For example, in a given time frame, 4 types of event may happen in time like this: 1,1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,4,3,4. More events (5,6,7... to infinity) are to come subsequently. How can I predict the next event of such a MTPP? Thank you for any idea.
